# I want to send keyboard keys to a specific program without having at at the top (python)

Tags: python, keyboard

So my Problem is that i want to send Keyboard keys to a program but without having at at the top so that i can do other things like writing some code and that just this specific program the keys become.

Comment: I do not think this can be done in general with Python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.